# File with the most lines in a directory NOT bytes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to to wc -l an entire directory and then display the filename in an echo with the number of lines.

To add to my frustration, the directory has to come from a passed argument.  So without looking stupid, can someone first tell me why a simple `wc -l $1` doesn't give me the line count for the directory I type in the argument?  I know i'm not understanding it completely.

On top of that I need validation too, if the argument given is not a directory or there is more than one argument.

Comment: `man wc` would tell you `wc [OPTION]... [FILE]...`.  `wc` operates on files, not directories.

Comment: @devnull, strictly speaking, directories are another type of files. On systems that allow opening and reading directories like regular files, `wc` would report the number of newline characters in the content of those directories (but that wouldn't be what the OP expects and wouldn't be useful)

Comment: Do you want to find the file with the most lines or display the files with their number of lines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`wc` works on files rather than directories so, if you want the word count on all files in the directory, you would start with:

```
wc -l $1/*
```

With various gyrations to get rid of the total, sort it and extract only the largest, you could end up with something like (split across multiple lines for readability but should be entered on a single line):

```
pax> wc -l $1/* 2>/dev/null
       | grep -v ' total$'
       | sort -n -k1
       | tail -1l

2892 target_dir/big_honkin_file.txt
```

As to the validation, you can check the number of parameters passed to your script with something like:

```
if [[ $# -ne 1 ]] ; then
    echo 'Whoa! Wrong parameteer count'
    exit 1
fi
```

and you can check if it's a directory with:

```
if [[ ! -d $1 ]] ; then
    echo 'Whoa!' "[$1]" 'is not a directory'
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want?

```
> find ./test1/ -type f|xargs wc -l
       1 ./test1/firstSession_cnaiErrorFile.txt
      77 ./test1/firstSession_cnaiReportFile.txt
   14950 ./test1/exp.txt
       1 ./test1/test1_cnaExitValue.txt
   15029 total
```

so your directory which is the argument should go here:

```
find $your_complete_directory_path/ -type f|xargs wc -l
```

Comment: It should be noted that that assumes `$your_directory` is a relative path (`./` prepended to it) and doesn't contain wildcard or blank characters (`$your_directory` not quoted) and that none of the file names contain blanks or quoting characters (`xargs` without `-0`).

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to to wc -l an entire directory and then display the
>   filename in an echo with the number of lines.

You can do a `find` on the directory and use `-exec` option to trigger `wc -l`. Something like this:

```
$ find ~/Temp/perl/temp/ -exec wc -l '{}' \;
wc: /Volumes/Data/jaypalsingh/Temp/perl/temp/: read: Is a directory
      11 /Volumes/Data/jaypalsingh/Temp/perl/temp//accessor1.plx
      25 /Volumes/Data/jaypalsingh/Temp/perl/temp//autoincrement.pm
      12 /Volumes/Data/jaypalsingh/Temp/perl/temp//bless1.plx
      14 /Volumes/Data/jaypalsingh/Temp/perl/temp//bless2.plx
      22 /Volumes/Data/jaypalsingh/Temp/perl/temp//classatr1.plx
      27 /Volumes/Data/jaypalsingh/Temp/perl/temp//classatr2.plx
       7 /Volumes/Data/jaypalsingh/Temp/perl/temp//employee1.pm
      18 /Volumes/Data/jaypalsingh/Temp/perl/temp//employee2.pm
      26 /Volumes/Data/jaypalsingh/Temp/perl/temp//employee3.pm
      12 /Volumes/Data/jaypalsingh/Temp/perl/temp//ftp.plx
      14 /Volumes/Data/jaypalsingh/Temp/perl/temp//inherit1.plx
      16 /Volumes/Data/jaypalsingh/Temp/perl/temp//inherit2.plx
      24 /Volumes/Data/jaypalsingh/Temp/perl/temp//inherit3.plx
      33 /Volumes/Data/jaypalsingh/Temp/perl/temp//persisthash.pm
```

Comment: That's great, this can then easily be piped to `sort`: `find ~/Temp/perl/temp/ -exec wc -l '{}' \; | sort`

Answer (score 1):

Nice question!

I saw the answers. Some are pretty good. The `find ...|xrags` is my most preferred. It could be simplified anyway using `find ... -exec wc -l {} +` syntax. But there is a problem. When the command line buffer is full a `wc -l ...` is called and every time a `<number> total` line is printer. As `wc` has no arg to disable this feature `wc` has to be reimplemented. To filter out these lines with [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) is not nice:

So my complete answer is

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

[ $# -ne 1 ] && echo "Bad number of args">&2 && exit 1
[ ! -d "$1" ] && echo "Not dir">&2 && exit 1
find "$1" -type f -exec awk '{++n[FILENAME]}END{for(i in n) printf "%8d %s\n",n[i],i}' {} +
```

Or using less temporary space, but a little bit larger code in [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
find "$1" -type f -exec awk 'function pr(){printf "%8d %s\n",n,f}FNR==1{f&&pr();n=0;f=FILENAME}{++n}END{pr()}' {} +
```

**Misc**

- If it should not be called for subdirectories then add `-maxdepth 1` before `-type` to [find](/questions/tagged/find).
- It is pretty fast. I was afraid that it would be much slower then the `find ... wc +` version, but for a directory containing 14770 files (in several subdirs) the [wc](/questions/tagged/wc) version run 3.8 sec and [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) version run 5.2 sec.
- [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) and [wc](/questions/tagged/wc) consider the not `\n` ended lines differently. The last line ended with no `\n` is not counted by [wc](/questions/tagged/wc). I prefer to count it as [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) does.
- It does not print the empty files

Comment: Note that the question title says _find the biggest file_

Comment: @sch: But in the question there is no any word about it.

Answer (score 0):

To find the file with most lines in the current directory and its subdirectories, with `zsh`:

```
lines() REPLY=$(wc -l < "$REPLY")
wc -l -- **/*(D.nO+lined[1])
```

That defines a `lines` function which is going to be used as a glob sorting function that returns in `$REPLY` the number of lines of the file whose path is given in `$REPLY`.

Then we use `zsh`'s recursive globbing `**/*` to find regular files (`.`), numerically (`n`) reverse sorted (`O`) with the `lines` function (`+lines`), and select the first one `[1]`. (`D` to include dotfiles and traverse dotdirs).

Doing it with standard utilities is a bit tricky if you don't want to make assumptions on what characters file names may contain (like newline, space...). With GNU tools as found on most Linux distributions, it's a bit easier as they can deal with NUL terminated lines:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    size=$(wc -c < "$file") &&
      printf "%s\0" "$size:$file"
  done' sh {} + |
  tr '\n\0' '\0\n' |
  sort -rn |
  head -n1 |
  tr '\0' '\n'
```

Or with zsh or GNU bash syntax:

```
biggest= max=-1
find . -type f -print0 |
  {
    while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
      size=$(wc -l < "$file") &&
        ((size > max)) &&
        max=$size biggest=$file
    done
    [[ -n $biggest ]] && printf '%s\n' "$max: $biggest"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that works for me with the git bash (mingw32) under windows:

```
find . -type f -print0| xargs -0 wc -l
```

This will list the files and line counts in the current directory and sub dirs. You can also direct the output to a text file and import it into Excel if needed:

```
find . -type f -print0| xargs -0 wc -l > fileListingWithLineCount.txt
```